# How to execute code / function when the application loads?

Tags: objective-c

How to execute code / function while the application is loading?

Comment: It's busy loading. You can't!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest you can get is putting your code directly after the application did finish launching in the respective method in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    int randomNumber = arc4random_uniform(100);

    NSLog(@"A random number between 0 and 100: %i", randomNumber);

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return YES;
}
```

**- OR -**

Put your code in the main.m file just before the app delegate becomes instantiated:

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        // PUT YOUR CODE HERE!
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([BCAppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

**UPDATE to your specific question from the comments:**

This code works for me: This is the complete code of a UIViewController implementation file!

```
//
//  WHEFirstViewController.m
//  a
//
//  Created by Ben Marten on 10.06.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Benjamin Marten. All rights reserved.
//

#import "WHEFirstViewController.h"

@implementation WHEFirstViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100.f, 100.f, 100.f, 100.f)];
    [button setTitle:@"Randomly Located Button" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    int x = arc4random_uniform(320);
    int y = arc4random_uniform(576);
    [button setCenter: CGPointMake(x,y)];

    [self.view addSubview:button];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@end
```

Comment: why in the second case not to see identifier?

Comment: int x = (arch4random() % 100) + 1; int y = (arch4random() % 100) + 1; _button.center=CGPointMake(x,y);

Comment: I don't understand, what do you mean?

Comment: I used the second case (int main), but shows an error xcode "Use of undeclared identifier '_button'

Comment: Ah ok I see... As far as I can see you are trying to put an UIButton randomly somewhere on the UIView of a UIViewController. Therefore both methods I described in my answer are not good. You should rather put this kind of code in the viewDidLoad: Method of the respective UIViewController!

Comment: I'm sorry, but this method does not work. I run the application, but the button does not change the coordinates

Comment: sure, check out my code! Please try to upvote comments/answers when they are helpful to you, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you want to execute some code before app delegates are called - main function is the entry point for the application ... you can write code in main or call a function.

Comment: For example: i want to get random number when app is loading.

Comment: you can do that in app delegate - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application willFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions